# Factor Analysis yielded The Big Five Personality: Were other statistical methods ever applied?

Tags: personality, statistics

It is known that Factor Analysis performed on personality survey data yielded what we know today as the Big Five. However, is Factor Analysis the only possible statistical method here? In particular, I am asking because FA assumes a linear relationship, which may not capture all relationships in the data.